# Why am I getting a 'UnicodeDecodeError' while I open an image through a file dialog box in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am a python beginner and I am writing a program for my school project. My aim is to **open an image file using a file dialog box.**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk()

root.title("Title")

root.filename = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir = "/Users/karan/Downloads", 
                                       title = "Select a file",
                                       filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpeg")))

my_lable = Label(root, text= root.filename)

my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
my_image_label = Label(image = my_image)
my_image_label.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

When I execute this program I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/karan/Documents/filedilog box.py", line 24, in <module>
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))

  File "/Users/karan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2977, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)

  File "/Users/karan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix this error?

(Other details- Python 3.8.8, Spyder IDE, Mac OS)

Thanks! for reading my question.

Comment: Try using `filedialog.askopenfilename` instead of `filedialog.askopenfile`. `filedialog.askopenfile` opens the file in `"r"` mode so you get a buffer and not a filename `str`ing.

Comment: `askopenfile` opens the file and returns the resulting file-like object, not the file name. The built-in `open` takes filenames and file-like objects with a file descriptor, so `fp` is just a wrapper around the text-mode file, not the binary-mode file expected.

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks a lot! You helped me fix the error.